# One modifier key not working after OSX upgrade

Tags: javascript, java, macos, jar

I use a jar file everyday at work that sorts photos by using hotkeys. A friend wrote the program but sadly has since passed away.

One of the commands enables you to copy a photo into an extra location by pressing "control" along with the hotkey. The photo viewer keeps that photo on the screen until you press a hotkey by itself, which advances to the next photo in the viewer. This works works perfectly on the macbook OSX Lion using java 6. 
But I needed to upgrade to a newer OSX. I have tried El Captitan, Sierra, High Sierra and Mojave with the newest Java. The program works perfectly except the one particular "control" modifier key I mentioned above. When pressed, not only does it not copy the photo as intended, it stops or freezes the program and I can only close the program and re-open it to continue on. 
I can use my backup and re-install everything back to original and everything works fine. Does anyone know why the modifier key would not function as programmed after an OSX upgrade? (I did try using the old java 6 on the newer OSX versions but no luck) 
Thank you

Comment: Can you get a copy of the original source code? I don't have an idea but showing the implementation for that "control" modifier key will greatly improve your chances at getting an answer. Also, [tag:javascript] != [tag:java] (_"Java is to JavaScript as ham is to hamster."_). Please pick one (most likely it's Java given it's a jar file) tag.

Comment: Also, what version of Java is this _"newest Java"_?